# Arranging PHP array based on pattern

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given the fallowing $array:

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [location_id_keep] => 25
        [location_id_delete] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [location_id_keep] => 26
        [location_id_delete] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 4
            )

    )

)
```

I want to group elements like the fallowing pattern to result:

```
Array (

[0] => Array
    (
        [location_id_keep] => 25
        [location_id_delete] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [location_id_keep] => 26
        [location_id_delete] => 3

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [location_id_keep] => 26
        [location_id_delete] => 4

    )

)
```

The rule should be like this, for each array from the input array, group the [location_id_keep] with each [location_id_delete] resulting a new array for each [location_id_delete] like in the desired output example.

What I tried so far :

```
foreach ($array as $id) {
//check if location_id_delete have more than 1 value
                if( $id["location_id_delete"][1]) {
                    foreach($id["location_id_delete"] as $del){
                         $array["location_id_delete"][] = $del;

                    $array["location_id_keep"]=id["location_id_keep"];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $id) {
//check if location_id_delete have more than 1 value
  if( is_array($id["location_id_delete"])) {
    foreach($id["location_id_delete"] as $del){
      $output[] = array(
        'location_id_keep' => $array[$i]["location_id_keep"],
        'location_id_delete' => $del
      );
    }
  }else{
    $output[] = $array[$i];
  }
}
var_dump($output);
```